# When using Leaflet and mapbox on mobile devices, white straight lines appear between tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

On iOS emulator, I am using **leaflet and Mapbox**, there are strange white lines between tiles. [image]

I really need your help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

8 months later, I've found out a way to fix it. You need to disable transform3d and replace it with regular transform in leaflet.

In leaflet-src.js change `any3d: !window.L_DISABLE_3D && (ie3d || webkit3d || gecko3d) && !opera12 && !phantomjs` to `any3d: false`. It should do the trick.

e: It causes very weird zoom in behaviour on mobile devices. so setting `any3d: mobile` should give better results.